# View text with the format of your choice?

Tags: java, unicode, websphere, ansi

I want to view a String (Java, copied out of Eclipse under Debug) with different encoding formats.  What is a good program with which to view them.  Or will that even work?

Notepad++ will convert it upon pasting to whichever format Notepad++ is currently set to use.  The real problem has to do with users copying text with special chars out of Word and pasting into a text-area.  Somewhere along the line both IE and Chrome seem convert the format of that field.  But that is not really my question.  At this point, I just want to be able to copy the String's value, paste it somewhere and choose the format to apply.

Answer (score 0):

[EditPad Pro](http://www.editpadpro.com/) for Windows has very comprehensive [encoding support](http://www.editpadpro.com/screens/textencoding.png); the best for Windows IMHO.

There is a [Pro](http://www.editpadpro.com/download.html) version and a [lite](http://www.editpadpro.com/download.html#trial) version if you just want to try it for free.

Answer (score 0):

I use MadEdit, works as a hex editor too. Open source and thus free

http://sourceforge.net/projects/madedit/

Keep in mind that when you copy and paste in windows it is usually copying characters and not reaw bytes. So with whatever tool you choose it will be important to have the encoding set before you paste in your data, as that will then set the bytes accordingly in the editor. You will then be able to view those bytes interpreted as different encodings.